# Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "Expires"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have this lambda function which creates a signed URL for the Object in bucket and return a URL to API gateway .

here is my lambda function code

```
import uuid
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    upload_key = uuid.uuid4().hex

    bucket = 'test-bucket-athena'


    # Generate the presigned URL for upload
    presigned_upload_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Key': upload_key,
            'Expires': 3600
        }
    )

    # return the result
    return {
        "upload_url": presigned_upload_url
        #"download_url": presigned_download_url
    }
```

When i run this code i get below error

> *[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "Expires", must be one of: Bucket, IfMatch,
> IfModifiedSince, IfNoneMatch, IfUnmodifiedSince, Key, Range,
> ResponseCacheControl, ResponseContentDisposition,
> ResponseContentEncoding, ResponseContentLanguage, ResponseContentType,
> ResponseExpires, VersionId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey,
> SSECustomerKeyMD5, RequestPayer, PartNumber, ExpectedBucketOwner
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
>     presigned_download_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/signers.py", line 586, in
> generate_presigned_url
>     request_dict = serializer.serialize_to_request(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 293, in serialize_to_request
>     raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())*

I thought the S3 url that i have provide is not in correct format but i tested all combination and nothing seems to be working

I have tried     below formats

```
bucket = 'test-bucket-athena'
bucket = 'test-bucket-athena/'
bucket = 's3://test-bucket-athena/'
bucket = 's3://test-bucket-athena'
bucket = 's3:///test-bucket-athena'
```

Please suggest what silly mistake i am doing here

Comment: you're code works for me using my own bucket in this format bucket = 'test-bucket-athena'; somehow it thinks Expires doesn't belong in your parameters, but not sure why

Comment: which boto3 version are you using?

Comment: hi @JonathanLeon i am using 1.17.88 boto3 version

Comment: i'm on '1.16.30' and the method looks to be the same with your version. generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod, Params=None, ExpiresIn=3600, HttpMethod=None) although this uses ExpiresIn and not Expires. maybe take it out of params and make same level as Params and ClientMethod????

Comment: When i removed 'ExpiresIn': 3600 or Expires i am able to get the url in response

Answer (score 0):

The bucketname should be in the format 'bucketname', just as you have on the first line:

```
bucket = 'test-bucket-athena'
```

But, I think you missed the error in the error message:

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "Expires", must be one of:
```

You have Expires in the Params section and its should actually be at the same level as Params.

```
presigned_upload_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Key': upload_key
        }, 
        ExpiresIn=3600
    )
```